# get specific text such as "Something new" using BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am making a focused crawler and facing an issue while find a for a key phrase in the document.

Supposing the key phrase I want to search in the document is "Something new"

using BeautifulSoup with python I do the following

```
if soup.find_all(text = re.compile("Something new",re.IGNORECASE)):
      print true
```

I want it to print true only for the following cases

"something new" --> true

"$#something new,." --> true

AND not for the following cases:

"thisSomething news" --> false

"Somethingnew" --> false

assuming special characters are allowed.

Has anyone ever done something like this before. ??

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then, search for `something new` and don't apply `re.IGNORECASE`:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<div>
    <span>something new</span>
    <span>$#something new,.</span>
    <span>thisSomething news</span>
    <span>Somethingnew</span>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for item in soup.find_all(text=re.compile("something new")):
    print item
```

Prints:

```
something new
$#something new,.
```

---

You can also take a non-regex approach and [pass a function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) instead of a compiled regex pattern:

```
for item in soup.find_all(text=lambda x: 'something new' in x):
    print item
```

For the example HTML used above, it also prints:

```
something new
$#something new,.
```

Comment: did pratikgala post his question wrong? All he wanted is to ignore case and symbols. But then he also wanted "Somethingnew" --> false. Which makes your answer perfect:-) But then I would have to remove my up vote for the question :p

Comment: @Md.Mohsin yeah, this is what made me think whether to post an answer or not. The code works for the inputs the OP provided, we'll see if there is smth else going on here. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the answer .  this worked for me 
soup.find_all(text = re.compile("\\bSomething new\\b",re.IGNORECASE))

Comment: @pratikgala word boundaries, good choice. Thanks for sharing. Is there anything else I can help you in this topic?

Comment: @pratikgala nice one, Thanks. Think you should make an answer yourself for others to know

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the alternative methods that I used:

```
soup.find_all(text = re.compile("\\bSomething new\\b",re.IGNORECASE))
```

Thanks everyone.